# Odoo get current form view model id

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I am trying to filter many2one [field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294858/odoo-how-to-filter-many2one-field-values-in-one2many-field)

by overwriting name_search function. In this function I want to get current form view model id. I was trying by creating variable:

```
context = self._context.get('active_ids')
```

But I am not getting any value.

Answer (score 0):

I use below example for current id of form

```
active_id = self.env.context.get('active_id', False)
```